# Jquery, append content from url

Tags: jquery, url, append, addition

Is there anyway to append some html content from a file in Jquery?

I know you can use load() in jquery to replace the entire content within an element.

but I wonder if I can conditionally use append('url') to add extra content into an element in Jquery

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
$.get('/someurl', function(result) {
    $('#someElement').append(result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So you are trying to append dynamic content? Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('<URL>', function(data){
    $(<contentelement>).append(<either entire data element, or do some operations on it>);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `append()` literally appends something to the end of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do a two step process, i.e

```
onclick='$("#id1").append("<div id=\"id2\"></div>"); $("#id2").load("content.php");'
```

This also works to prepend content from another url too.